# Need Help To Build A Navbar

Tags: html, css, web

How to build A Navbar Like This website (codewithharry) by Using flexbox
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gn8K.png)

Pls Provide the source link Or explain me pls
or share the link of any tutorial
MAKE SURE TO USE FLEXBOX mostly And i dont want to use bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use Bootstrap. Here's a link:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can find a basic Bootstrap 4 Basic Template with a NAV bar here:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_templates.asp

Note that the primary difference between Bootstrap3 and Bootstrap4 is the switch from using floats to flexbox.

References:

[A quick, concise video tutorial to flexbox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc)

[An excellent interactive cheatsheet for flexbox](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/)

[A Bootstrap3 tutorial that includes a NAV bar - worth working through even for Bootstrap4](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp)